# Highcharts's pie chart minSize option not working

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

is it just me or is the option `plotOptions.pie.minSize` from Highcharts non functional??

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/totszwai/xr7wqpn1/

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.minSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minSize` does not work as you think it does. It does not set a minimum size for the pie, it merely set the minimum size of the pie in regards to the auto margins caused by labels being present.

You can test this out by enabling labels in your fiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/xr7wqpn1/7/

Here are 2 examples to illustrate what `minSize` changes:

**Screenshot with `minSize: 200`**

[image]

**Screenshot with `minSize: 400`**

[image]

If your goal is to set the size of a chart, use css instead, set `min-width` and `max-width`. JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/xr7wqpn1/20/

Comment: Any way to prevent the pie from being auto resize to a point is not usable then? Basically something equivalent to `min-width`

Comment: You can use `min-width`, see this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/xr7wqpn1/19/